# Neo4J Not Require Relationship for Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using this Query to get Family Tree of a family, It works fine if every branch has 3 generations, but as long as one generation doesn't have children, it won't get the children of other branches.
This is my Query

```
Match p=(a:Person)-[a1:PARENT_OF]->(b:Person)-[b1:PARENT_OF]->(c:Person) 
where a.ID='9101'
WITH a,b,a1,b1,{id:c.ID,name:c.TEN,gioitinh:c.GIOI_TINH,loaiqh:b1.type} as thehe1
WITH a,a1,b1,{id:b.ID,name:b.TEN,gioitinh:b.GIOI_TINH,loaiqh:a1.type,loaiqh1:b1.type, children:collect(thehe1)} as thehe2
WITH  {id:a.ID,name:a.TEN,gioitinh:a.GIOI_TINH,loaiqh:a1.type, children:collect(thehe2)} as phahe 
return phahe
```

That happen when one or more Person (b) don't have Children, that mean Relationship (b1) and (c) don't exist in that case. Query will return just 2 generations for all Person (b) but But not all (b) don't have children that make my Query lack of data.

What should I do to make the Relationship (b1) not Require? Sorry for my bad English and Thanks!

Comment: maybe you're looking for `optional match` https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

Comment: actually maybe variable length relationships would be better https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH p=(a:Person)-[a1:PARENT_OF]->(b:Person)
WHERE a.ID='9101'
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[b1:PARENT_OF]->(c:Person)
WITH a, a1,
  {id:b.ID, name:b.TEN, gioitinh:b.GIOI_TINH, loaiqh:a1.type,
   loaiqh1: CASE WHEN b1 IS NOT NULL THEN b1.type END,
   children: CASE WHEN b1 IS NOT NULL THEN COLLECT({id:c.ID,name:c.TEN,gioitinh:c.GIOI_TINH,loaiqh:b1.type}) ELSE [] END} as thehe2
RETURN  {id:a.ID,name:a.TEN,gioitinh:a.GIOI_TINH,loaiqh:a1.type, children:collect(thehe2)} as phahe
```